# 「要求された参照キーは…」の意味

Tags: sql-server

RPA用のソフトウェアをインストールしている際に、

「要求された参照キーはどのアクティブなアクティブ化コンテキストにも見つかりませんでした」
とのメッセージが現れました。
何が原因でこのメッセージが現れるのでしょうか。

そのソフトウェアのインストール前に、
・SQL Server (2014)
・IIS 7.5

等をインストールし、SQL Server状のDBと連携する設定を行ってインストールしていますが、
それが何か関係あるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

問題のエラーはSQL ServerやIISに固有のものではありません。Windowsの機能に由来する一般的なメッセージですのでそれだけでは原因の特定は難しいです。

メッセージ中の*アクティブ化コンテキスト*([activation context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff951641(v=vs.85).aspx))はサイドバイサイド構成のものを指していると思われます。これはDLLの読み込みやCOMオブジェクトの生成に際して利用されるものです。ですのでインストール時に行われるはずの何らかの登録が正常に行われなかったのだと考えられます。

ですので対処方法としてはアプリケーションもしくはOSの再インストールぐらいしかありません。とりあえず問題のソフトウェアのサポート窓口に確認したほうが良いと思います。

Comment: インストールのステータスが、Applying permissions information for objects...となっているので、確かにCOMオブジェクト等に権限を与えているときのエラーと推測しています。いろんな方法でアプリケーションのインストールを試しています。